# Is there any Intel intrinsic in gcc for this bit select operation?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, bit-manipulation, intrinsics

I have a 16-bit unsigned integer `U`, and ten 16-bit unsigned integers `T1`, `T2`, ..., `T10`. For each `TX`, there's an associated 16-bit mask, let's call it `MX`.

The value of each `TX` is the result of taken the bits of U at the positions where its corresponding `MX` is set to 1, but pasted sequentially. Example, consider:

```
U:     0010101101001110
MX:    0010111010101011
```

The bits set as 0 in MX must be ignored from U. I have marked those bits with `-`s:

```
U:     --1-101-0-0-1-10
MX:    0010111010101011
```

Now, the select bits of `U` must be placed together at TX, so TX is:

```
U:     --1-101-0-0-1-10
MX:    0010111010101011
TX:    1101001100000000
```

Since `MX` selected 8 bits from `U`, the last 8 bits of TX are all 0. I don't care whether the taken bits are placed together at the beginning or the end of TX as far as  they are place together and I know where they are.

What is the most efficient way to do it? What options do I have to solve this problem in constant time per-MX? Is there any Intel intrinsic provided by gcc that I can use? Or even better, is there any MMX instruction so that I can do this operation in groups of two or four TX's?

Comment: This seems like the PEXT instruction, but with the step of aligning with the highest order bit instead. You could do this in constant time with PEXT, LZCNT, SHR.

Comment: @Locke that's looks really really nice than you

Comment: Not sure how you'd use LZCNT usefully here.  ROR(PEXT(U, MX), POPCNT(MX)) would do it in 3 instructions.

Comment: Please read the [ask] help page. I think the title here could be made more descriptive of the actual question.

Comment: If you don't care where they're placed, high or low end of the destination, you can just use `pext`.  If you want them at the top, that's inconvenient especially on an Intel CPUs (where variable-count shift/rotate is 3 uops, except BMI2 no-flags shifts which don't have a variable-count rotate.)  So  @ChrisDodd's suggestion is 5 uops, but probably lower latency since `popcnt` can run in parallel with `pext`.  Locke's idea to `_lzcnt_u16 (pext_result)` to get a left-shift count (to remove all its leading zero bits) can be 3 uops on Intel with `shlx`, but 3+3+1 cycle critical path latency.

Comment: AMD CPUs don't have that problem with variable-count rotates (or pre-BMI2 shifts), but only Zen3 and later have fast BMI2 pext/pdep; before that it's disastrously slow, with microcode that doesn't have real hardware support.  But anyway, good thing you can use the bits at the bottom of a register instead of the top.

Comment: There's no instruction to pext in parallel on SIMD vector elements.  And probably not worth trying to SWAR.  Although I think you could repeat 4 copies of `U` in a 64-bit register (`uint64_t`) and run `pext` with a concatenation of 4 different masks.  Then you'd get the result packed together in 4 bitfields with width = `popcnt(MX)`, so different widths, leaving you needing to do those popcounts to get shift and `bzhi` counts to extract the results.

Comment: @PeterCordes in my machine I have observed that changing the code I have with `pext` makes it much slower. The code I have assigns bits individually on a loop, and I'm still figure it out why this constant-time operation is slower than the loop.

Comment: What machine do you have?  Is it an AMD older than Zen3?  If so, that's expected, like I mentioned.  In such machines, `pext` is *not* constant-time, it's very slow microcode.  AMD only introduced fast hardware for `pext` with Zen3. See https://uops.info/, although they don't time the worst case.  If you have an Intel CPU, or Zen3 or Zen4, then probably you're using `pext` wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes an Intel Core i5-8350. I'll try to create a minimal-reproducible example and post another question to ask why it's now slower and how to improve it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was wrong. It's faster, although not as faster as I expected, but faster. It was slower but because I was doing something wrong with the bits that made slower the code that came later.